Can a Seed be Linked Across Two Multisig Wallets?
Consider two multisig wallets, Wallet A and Wallet B, both with a 2-of-3 signing scheme:
Wallet A consists of seeds A, B, and C.
Wallet B consists of seeds B, C, and D.
Now, let's create two transactions:
Transaction 1 is a spend from Wallet A, signed by seeds B and C.
Transaction 2 is a spend from Wallet B, also signed by seeds B and C.
Question:
Will the use of the same seeds in different wallets inherently link these wallets, and therefore, the transactions? How does this affect the privacy and security of the wallets involved?
